# meaning and reading of 心楽しい

Tags: translation, readings

I have the following (part of a) sentence

```
そして疲れていながらも心楽しかった。
```

I found several references to 心楽しい online but my search on several directories was unsuccessful regarding meaning and way of regarding.
So, what does it mean and what is the typical reading?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think this is a typo for 心から楽しかった or 心底楽しかった...

Comment: Oh, not again a typo.. :(

Comment: @naruto, might just be [a rare term](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BF%83%E6%A5%BD-2038066) rather than a typo.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi, thanks a lot I didn't know about that site!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not know that word... [BCCWJ Shonagon](https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/) has 17 examples of 心楽しい, most of which are by authors born in or before the 1940's. Although it's almost a dead word, it may be still be used in serious literary works written by a young author. @EiríkrÚtlendi Do you want to post an answer for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

心楽しい is literally their hearts having fun or enjoying. Saying the word heart is like saying "coming from the heart or literally their heart" so there's that "sincerity" connotation rather than just simply saying "楽しい". Another connotation is that it has this peaceful, soothing, soft feeling, when you enjoy or find something pleasant.

Basically, it is something similar to "enjoying" or "pleasant feeling" or "being happy about something." but the connotations that comes with it are a bit hard to translate in english.

[This](https://meigennavi.net/kw/k/kokoro-tanoshii.htm) shows an example as to how it is used.

> (1) 何の心配もない世界で（の）ストレスもひずみもない生活を想像するのは**心楽しい**ことかもしれないが、これは怠け者の夢にすぎない。
>
> translation: It might be **nice/pleasant/delightful** to imagine a life without any stress or strain in a world free from worry, but isn't that too much of a dream(wishful thinking) for a lazy person?

and

> (2)人を愛する前に、自分を愛さなければなりません。自分自身を受け入れ、**心楽しく** あなた自身でいることによって、あなたは自分の能力を発揮し、ただそこにいるだけで、周りの人を幸せにします。
>
> translation: Before you love a person, you must love yourself. Embrace yourself, by **enjoying/being happy about** being yourself, show your abilities, just by being there, you'll make the people around you happy.

another example is this quote by Margaret Mitchell

> (3)やがていつかは身も軽く、**心楽しい**朝が来よう
>
> translation: Eventually, we'll be in a better place someday. A **lovely/delightful/pleasant/enjoyable** morning will come.

Lastly one of the examples [here](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E5%BF%83%E6%A5%BD%E3%81%97%E3%81%84) already has a given translation.

> (4)中でもいちばん**心楽しい**方法は、どこかの高級レストランで豪勢な食事をとることだ。
>
> Translation: The **pleasantest** was to dine luxuriously at some expensive restaurant - O Henry "The Cop and the Anthem"

so depending on the whole context of what you are reading

> そして疲れていながらも心楽しかった。
>
> Could be translated as **"And despite being tired, I (sincerely) had fun.(it was enjoyable/delightful)"**

Hope this helps and made things clearer.